Are other people experiencing this iPhone 16 spotlight search bug
Letter S causes spotlight search to erase.
Got new iPhone 16 pro
Cloned iPhone 14 pro with ios 18
If I pull down on screen to start a search and type the letter S, it displays but then the entire field is cleared.
I can search for Settings, Safari or Skype only by using keyboard swipes to enter the entire word at once.
Only the letter S causes the field to erase itself.
Here is my video:
https://share.icloud.com/photos/094K4wUaEuRuC7WwgUTXq_rPg
I have tried many things, such as resetting settings, turning off all shortcuts and keyboard features, disabling search and siri options, using different keyboards, and upgrading to 18.1 beta. Nothing works.
Is this happening on other iPhone 16s?
Does anybody know what would cause it?

Yes, this is pretty widely reported now.  Please report it to Apple.  The more visibility it gets the better chance it has of getting fixed in the next update.  Also, if you didn't figure out a workaround is just to type the next character very quickly.
